# JQuery DataTables: Unable to sort column after adding columnDefs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable, coffeescript

I have a table in my Rails application which displays a single column of dates, written in US long form (Month DD, YYYY).

Using a default dataTable, I noticed that these date strings are sorted alphabetically, rather than by date. Clicking the column header will sort those strings in ascending or descending order as expected, but alphabetically.

I tried to get the datatable to properly sort by date by modifying my CoffeeScript to include columnDefs, as follows:

```
  $('.scheduled_activities').dataTable(
    columnDefs: [ { 'type': 'date', 'targets': 0 } ]
  )
```

After altering the script, the datatable now displays the dates in ascending order. Clicking on the column header, however, does absolutely nothing -- dates are not sorted in descending order.

How can I get datatables to recognize the column values as dates while retaining the ability to sort in asc/desc order by clicking on the column header? I'm using JQuery 1.11.2, and I'd like to stick with a solution with as few dependencies as possible, so using libraries like moment.js are a last resort. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables couldn't sort my column because the dates in the column were actually links created via the Rails `link_to` helper, rather than simple strings.

I tried different [types](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) for my `columnDefs`, but none of them could interpret a column of links properly. It occurred to me that I could de-link the date string and creat a second column with a `link_to` that linked to the object to which the date referred. While this approach technically met the requirement that dates be both sortable while providing access to the underlying object, having a series of links in a second column was aesthetically displeasing, mainly because none of the other tables in my application force the user to click a secondary link.

As it happens, [DataTables 1.10+ can leverage HTML 5 data attributes](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) to provide a piece of data to be used in sorting while displaying a different piece of data between the `<td>` tags.

Old Code:

```
<% @schedulable_activities.each do | activity | %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "#{localize_date(activity.start_date)}", activity_path(activity) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

New Code:

```
<% @schedulable_activities.each do | activity | %>
  <tr>
    <td data-order="<%= activity.start_date%>">
      <%= link_to "#{localize_date(activity.start_date)}", activity_path(activity) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Note the `data-order` attribute in the `<td>` tag.

With this change, I could revert to a "plain Jane" invocation of DataTables, without having to rely on `columnDefs` at all:

```
$ ->
  $('.scheduled_activities').dataTable()
```

Now I get a table that properly sorts by date in both ascending and descending order by clicking on the column header, as well as a direct link to the object associated with the date.

Answer (score 1):

***Option 1:***
If you look at the https://www.datatables.net/manual/options, there is an option for setting order to true or false, simply set order to false.

```
//Example
$('#example').DataTable( {
  ordering: false
} );
```

> Here we disable the ordering feature of DataTables by
>   default, you can even disable searching by setting 'searching' to false

***Option 2***
if you find that columns sorting is disabled in option one, then replace the ***ordering: false*** line with ***"aaSorting": []*** so it becomes:

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
  "aaSorting": []
} );
```

for more on option 2 follow this doc https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#aaSorting

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about coffee syntax but in javascript that syntax is invalid. Missing `{}` to define the object that `columnDefs` is a property of

```
$('.scheduled_activities').dataTable({
    columnDefs: [ { 'type': 'date', 'targets': 0 } ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that syntax is correct for CoffeeScript. Curiously, the additional braces don't break the script, but neither do they improve the situation.